Web containers vitest failing
I'm trying to build a wrapper around Stackblitz's web containers for my documentation. I'm using a javaScript class for this:
import {WebContainer, FileSystemTree} from "@webcontainer/api";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import {fileURLToPath} from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default class Container {
  private mContainer!: WebContainer;

  constructor() {
    this.CreateContainer();
    this.ScaffoldViteApp();
    this.StartDevServer();
  }

  private CreateContainer = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer = await WebContainer.boot();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  };

  private ScaffoldViteApp = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer.spawn("npm", [
        "create",
        "vite",
        "container-example -- --template react-swc-ts"
      ]);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  };

  private StartDevServer = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer.spawn("npm", ["run", "dev"]);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  };

  public SetComponent(name: string) {
    const files: FileSystemTree = {
      "Component.tsx": {
        file: {
          contents: fs.readFileSync(
            path.join(
              __dirname,
              "../../apps/components",
              name.toLowerCase(),
              `${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}.tsx`
            )
          )
        }
      }
    };

    try {
      this.mContainer.fs.mkdir("components");
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    try {
      this.mContainer.mount(files, {mountPoint: "components"});
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  }

  public GetIframe() {
    return this.mContainer.on("server-ready", (port, url) => {
      return url;
    });
  }

  public WriteComponent(name: string, content: string) {
    const files: FileSystemTree = {
      "Component.tsx": {
        file: {
          contents: content
        }
      }
    };

    try {
      this.mContainer.mount(files, {mountPoint: "components"});
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  }
}

And I'm testing it with Vitest:
import Container from "../createContainer";
import {it, describe, expect, vi, beforeEach} from "vitest";

describe("CreateContainer", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it("should create a container with a basic vite project when the class is initialized", () => {
    const container = new Container();
  });

  it("should load a specified component into the container", () => {
    const container = new Container();
    container.SetComponent("example");
  });

  it("should return the url to the container's iframe", () => {
    const container = new Container();
    container.GetIframe();
  });

  it("should write changes to the component on the container", () => {
    const container = new Container();
    container.WriteComponent("example", "console.log('Hello World')");
  });
});

However, all of my test are failing with no message just {}. What could be causing this? I'm trying to mock the window before each test but still the same errors occur.
